# Pronouncable passwords?

Tags: algorithm, passwords

Modules or software solutions for generating English pronounceable passwords?

Are there similar modules for other languages?

-Adam

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to investigate the [Markov chain method](http://www.google.com/search?q=pronounceable+markov). Here's an example:

- http://www.multicians.org/thvv/gpw.html

and here are some auto-generated passwords:

- http://www.manic.org/new/pw/pron.html

Comment: Currently, the www.multicans.org link is flagged as distributing malware by my virus scanner.

Answer (score 2):

You should look for [polygen](http://polygen.org/), unfortunately I don't know if there is an english version too of the software. It generates random words/sentences using determinated rule you choose (the site contains very funny things but in Italian only :\ The rules can be written in any language.)

Answer (score 2):

Once upon a time I put together my own extremely simple generator.  It was just a dictionary with a couple thousand 3-5 letter English words.  To make a password, I'd cat 2 of them together and append a (pseudo)random two-digit number.

2000 * 2000 * 90 = 360 Million possible combinations (dependent, of course, on the pseudo-random mechanism used to select the words).  Not as good as a "professional" product, but maybe good enough depending on what you want to use it for.